# PowerShell remove characters between 2 different characters in string

Tags: powershell

I have a string in Powershell

```
vavccdetdq12.store.com2330;vavcwscdeprd34.store.com3225;vavcsacdeprd56.store.com3226
```

I want it to look like

```
vavccdetdq12.store.com;vavcwscdeprd34.store.com;vavcsacdeprd56.store.com
```

Comment: So you want to remove the trailing digits from each host name?

Comment: Yes, maybe I just need to parse into an array and then remove?

Comment: `'vavccdetdq12.store.com2330;vavcwscdeprd34.store.com3225;vavcsacdeprd56.store.com3226' -replace '\.com\d+', '.com'`

Comment: `-replace '\d+(?=;|$)'` would work I think.

Comment: Or if you like to split into an array first: `('vavccdetdq12.store.com2330;vavcwscdeprd34.store.com3225;vavcsacdeprd56.store.com3226' -split ';' | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '\d+$' }) -join ';'`

Answer (score 0):

If it is always a group of 4 digits you want to remove, you can do it like this:

```
$string = 'vavccdetdq12.store.com2330;vavcwscdeprd34.store.com3225;vavcsacdeprd56.store.com3226'

$string -replace '\d{4}', ''
```

Which gives this output:

`vavccdetdq12.store.com;vavcwscdeprd34.store.com;vavcsacdeprd56.store.com`

Comment: Might not always be 4 digits.

Comment: You should specify that in your question.